# Can't figure out the phrase "designer birdhouses" in this headline

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

A headline in the New York Times is:

> "The Designer Birdhouses of Brooklyn"

What is a "designer birdhouse"? Is it a birdhouse made by a designer?

I've never come across a phrase like that. I would have said "a stylefull birdhouse", because "designer" is a noun.

Comment: Aside: if you actually did need an alternative, meaning "having style", the typical choice would be "stylish" not "stylefull".

Comment: Even if _stylefull_ was a word (it isn't), it would be spelled with one `L`, not two.  When you use `-ful` as a suffix, it's one-L-of-a-suffix

Comment: Doesn't the article make the meaning clear?

Comment: Designer jeans (back in the 1980s), designer sunglasses, designer sneakers...articles which have been styled by a designer. Yes, *designer* **is a noun** but when placed in front of another noun it becomes an attributive noun or noun adjunct, think of *goat cheese* and *table mat*.

Comment: @Flydog57, +1 for giving the correct spelling of a non-existent word .  So, in the same vein, could you confirm that "paradiscombobulatingosity" has only one "m" and no silent "q"?

Answer (score 14):

The adjective **designer** is meant as an analogy to "fashion designer", like Marc Jacobs or Cristóbal Balenciaga.

A "designer" product is a fashionable, stylish, and usually expensive luxury product. So a "designer birdhouse" is a fashionable, luxurious, and probably expensive birdhouse.

Sometimes it's used in a mildly pejorative sense, implying that the buyer of a "designer" product is vain, materialistic, and/or financially irresponsible.

I think that using "stylish" as a synonym might work in general, but misses some of the connotation.

Comment: The term *designer* is not an adjective, if it were we would be able to say: "That's a very designer birdhouse" or "Which birdhouse is the most designer?" Please cite a source which clearly says the word "designer"  is an adjective. Instead it is used as an *attributive noun* aka *noun adjunct* Think: apple pie, table mat, bus stop, goat cheese, summer dress etc.

Comment: My bad, Cambridge and Lexico both say "designer" is an adjective. Argghhh, 35 years of grammar down the drain.

Comment: Indeed. There are a number of tests for adjectivehood, no one of which is decisive. There are other adjectives which cannot be used predicatively, or can only be used predicatively. I would say that in its origtinal sense _designer_ was indeed an attributive noun, but in its transferred sense it is adjectival.

Answer (score 9):

A quick search shows that one of the meanings of the word "designer" is as an adjective or, more accurately, an ***attributive noun*** (see @Mary-Lou A's [comment](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/317006/cant-figure-out-the-phrase-designer-birdhouses-in-this-headline/317010?noredirect=1#comment595129_317010) below, and [this article](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/nouns-that-look-like-adjectives)) and is something like this:

> To have been made by, or to have the expensive sophistication of, a famous and prestigious designer.

But there is a variation on that precise meaning which might apply in this context. It is something like this:

> ***Appearing*** to have been made by, or to have the expensive sophistication of, a famous and prestigious fashion designer.

In other words, it might not be unreasonable, in this context, to interpret "designer" as a form of marketing BS; what the *Wikipedia Manual of Style* might call [puffery](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Manual_of_Style/Words_to_watch#Puffery) or a "peacock term".

Note that I say only that it *might* be marketing BS. For all I know, the birdhouses in question were designed by Michael Kors, influenced by Frank Lloyd Wright, and have four floors, twelve bedrooms, pool, servants quarters, and grand entrance hall complete with gold-trimmed furniture and a swing.

Comment: I read the article. They are designed by various people, including artists (professional and amateur) and architects.

Comment: Fair enough. But would you agree that the word "designer" is often used in the additional sense I mentioned?  That is in an attempt to give something the *appearance* of (without actually having) the class, or style, etc that a good designer would produce. A similar thing happens with words like "Professional"; as in, say, the *Moleskine PRO* range of notebooks. Hmm -- but there it's even worse. These days the various meanings of "professional" have all strayed very far from its original roots, and none of seems applicable to a notebook! I believe there is a word for this phenomenon.

Comment: I thoroughly agree. In fact, before I actually read the article, I thought the NYT was sneering at fashionable pretence. I have seen a sneering UK use of 'designer', e.g. my sister-in-law is so up herself she uses designer toilet paper. Maybe it's used like that in the US.

Comment: Designer birdcage, designer birdhouse, the term *designer* is not an adjective, if it were we would be able to say: "That's a very designer birdhouse" or "Which bird cage is the most designer?" Please cite a source which clearly states that the word "designer" is an adjective. Instead, it is used as an *attributive noun* aka *noun adjunct*. Think: apple pie, table mat, bus stop, goat cheese, summer dress etc.

Comment: I see Cambridge says "designer" is an adjective when it's used before a noun. Harumph, never heard anyone say of something: "They are (very) designer."

Comment: Hmm. I hadn't heard of the *attributive noun* until you mentioned it, but now that you have, I reckon you're right and that "designer" is in fact a perfect example of one! And that's supported by checking "designer" against the criteria given at the end of [this article](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/nouns-that-look-like-adjectives). I'm inclined to think that Cambridge (presumably you meant something like [this](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/spellcheck/english/?q=Attributive+noun)) is simply being a bit imprecise.

Comment: In fact, I reckon your *attributive noun* is the correct answer to the OP's question. I'm about to modify my own answer to reflect what you've said, but I'd encourage you to elevate your comment to a full-blown answer. If you do, it gets my vote I'd recommend the OP accept it.

Comment: I wonder how usage like "designer drug" fits into all this. On the one hand, perhaps some attributive nouns morph into adjectives over time. On the other hand, it still fails to meet one of the criteria in the article I linked to. Namely, while we can say *"X is a designer drug"*, we would never say, *"X is a drug that is designer"*

Comment: Hmm. OTOH, the rules of order of descriptive words might give us a clue as to whether "designer" is an adjective or an attributive noun. Suppose a brilliant medication was just released, intended to help slow biological aging. And I'd say that "designer" is conveying either *origin* or *type* information. So if "designer" were an attributive noun, then we'd say, *"X is an amazing, new, anti-aging designer drug"*. However, were it an adjective, we'd say, *"X is an amazing, new, designer anti-aging drug"*. Which of the two is more idiomatic? I have no idea! 

Comment: @tkp I would definitely say that the second is more idiomatic. It becomes clearer if you remove the "amazing, new": a "designer anti-aging drug" is much more idiomatic than an "anti-aging designer drug"

Comment: @tkp I would consider "black designer boots" and "designer leather boots" to both be more idiomatic than their respective alternatives. fwiw, Google Ngrams agrees with me. I guess that puts "designer" in the "origin" category for adjectives?

Comment: Yeah, but it's making me grumpy. I was all pleased with the new (to me) concept of *attributive noun* to which @Mari-LouA introduced me, and I felt that "designer" was a good example, only to confuse myself by trying to make a supporting argument from adjective order. I thought that if I could show that it was impossible to idiomatically insert even a *purpose* adjective after "designer" then since the latter is conveying, yes, *origin* (or perhaps *type*) then that would show that it could *not* be an adjective.  But as we see, with both anti-aging drugs and leather boots, I failed. Bleh.

Comment: I have much to say on the order of descriptive words, having a copy of Quirk in my lap, but it probably belongs in a chat room instead.

Comment: Quirk. That’s the second new thing I've learned here today. At the risk of sounding like an uneducated ignoramus, is it worth having? And do you know how it compare with Huddleston, say? (Isn't it amazing how even in a subject about which one knows very little, it is easy to quickly find leads for further exploration by simply adding, to the end of an internet search, the word, "versus" or its abbreviation, “vs”. These days, with the likes of Google, you don’t have to hit `Enter`.)

Answer (score 7):

A designer birdhouse is either one made by a fashionable or famous birdhouse designer, or a fashionable looking birdhouse.

The article (by Winnie Hu, *New York Times* 9 June 2022) says:

> During lockdown, birdsong replaced traffic noise. Those who miss it
> can visit Brooklyn Botanic Garden, which just installed 33 new
> designer birdhouses.
>
> I stopped by for a first look

The article discusses birdhouses ('bird houses' in British English, I should think) designed by various artists for a Brooklyn, New York City public garden.

> designer
>
> adjective [ before noun ]   MARKETING, PRODUCTION
>
> made by a famous or fashionable designer:
> designer jeans/sunglasses
>
> **made to interest or attract people by being new and fashionable:**

[Designer (adjective) Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/designer)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

We sometimes transform nouns into adjectives in English and use them to describe other nouns. Often this is done playfully, as in these common examples:  work wife (someone you are not married to but spend a lot of time with at work.) man hands (This was made famous on the old television show Seinfeld where it described the large man-like hands of a woman.) television show -- a show on television.

A designer is a person who designs something: "Thelma is a designer. She designs living spaces."

Using "designer" as an adjective in front of another noun, means that noun was designed by someone. It often denotes that object as special, artistic, fashionable, unique, etc.
Examples:  Gloria Vanderbilt was a pioneer of designer jeans.
The condo includes a designer kitchen with upscale appliances.
The dress she wore to the ceremony was a designer original.

Answer (score 1):

"designer" in "designer birdhouses" is *not* a noun, but an adjective, as @MichaelHarvey mentioned. You could call it a "stylish/fashionable/elegant birdhouse" instead, there is no such word called "stylefull". These birdhouses are probably made by a professional or a famous birdhouse designer.

[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/designer) gives this definition of "designer":

> 1. Made or designed by a famous and prestigious fashion designer.
>
> - ‘designer clothes’
>
> 2. Upscale and fashionable.
>
> - ‘designer food’

Comment: Good to know that you are adding attributions in your answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

'Designer' as a prefix suggests that the product benefits from professional design, and usually sets it apart from cheaper, mass-produced equivalents. For example, a 'designer handbag' would be one from a known luxury fashion house, as opposed to an unbranded, or 'off-brand' product.

However, it is also common to use the word more glibly, such as for products where there are no well-known designers but when the product appears to be more expensive than comparable ones, or there is an attempt to make it more elaborate so as to appeal to a different market. It can even be used to show disdain for overly-expensive products and 'showy' people that may buy them simply because they appear expensive. Your quotation may be an example of this, as birdhouses are not something known to be a 'designer' product. In fact, the majority of birdhouses tend to follow a 'classic' design and are made from simple timber products. The article seems sincere, though, so in this case, I would read 'designer' to mean they are high-quality artisanal products.